# regex to extract matching text and any number from email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to extract the order number like "SPR 0002745"  (starting with "SPR" plus one space and followed by a 7 digit number - with preceding zeros) from an email I receive. I will "star" and mark the email as "important" in Gmail. Then I will run the below function.

I want to extract an amount (a number - maybe with comma , maybe with a decimal) found in the email.

I am not able to use regex. Getting null as output.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var filter = "label:inbox has:nouserlabels is:important in:Starred"; 
  var threads = GmailApp.search(filter);  
  if (threads.length == 0) {
    ss.toast("No message without label, marked star and important", "Remove label, mark star and important first", -1); 
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) { // Loop through the threads
    var thisThread = threads[i]; // Get a speific thread
    var messages = thisThread.getMessages(); // Get the messages in that thread
    var messageCount = thisThread.getMessageCount(); // Count the number of messages in that thread
    var lastMessage = messages[messageCount - 1]; // Get the last message in that thread. The first message is numbered 0.
    break;
  }
  var message = lastMessage;
  var body = message.getPlainBody();//body field
  Logger.log(body);//working 
  var complaintno = body.match(/^SPR\ (.*)$/)
  Logger.log(complaintno); //returnig null
  var amount1 = body.match(/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:(\.|,)\d+)?$/); 
  var amount2 = body.match(/^([0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+)$/);
  Logger.log(amount1);//returnig null
  Logger.log(amount2);//returnig null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) the order number you described: `var complaintno = body.match(/SPR \d{7}/)` (*SPR* followed by a space and seven digits). For example:

```
function testRegex() {
  const body = 'Exercitationem commodi enim hic sunt maiores. Aperiam sunt praesentium fugit rem nemo et accusantium. Aut ab est sit mollitia eaque. Aliquam hic vel ut tempore quo quia enim nostrum. Quia aut qui ex voluptatibus: SPR 0002745 Ullam vel asperiores ut suscipit repellat. Velit porro qui et sunt et ea doloremque. Ipsum modi in dolores rerum.';
  const complaintNumber = body.match(/SPR \d{7}/)[0];
  Logger.log(complaintNumber); // This outputs SPR 0002745
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working. But, the number is not coming.

Comment: I added a sample code to the answer that works for me.

Comment: Sorry. The first part (complaint number) is working. The second part where I want the amount is not working.   var amount1 = body.match(/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:(\.|,)\d+)?$/); 
  var amount2 = body.match(/^([0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+)$/); both not working

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is the kind of data you want to extract, but both of these expressions only work if the data to be extracted are by themselves in a line, because `^` matches the beginning of the string, and `$` matches the end. That's why in my answer I didn't include them. So it really depends on what you're trying to do. You might want to take a deeper look at how regular expressions work: http://www.rexegg.com/ And there are tools that can help you create regexes: https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org/

Comment: I receive a mail from customer when he makes a payment. The amount will be written in the mail somewhere. I need to extract that number and use it further. The number may be in xxxxxxxxxx or xx,xx,xxx or xxxxx.xx or  xx,xx,xxx.xx format. Nothing else should match